# From where have Taylor theorem popped out?

Tags: calculus

I have learnt that taylor representation is generalization of MVT . But are there any other sources from where taylor series have popped out ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is $n$ times continuously differentiable on $[a,b]$ then

$$\frac{d}{dt}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(b-a)^k}{k!}f^{(k)}[a + t(b-a)](1-t)^k \\=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(b-a)^{k+1}}{k!}f^{(k+1)}[a + t(b-a)](1-t)^k - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(b-a)^k}{(k-1)!}f^{(k)}[a + t(b-a)](1-t)^{k-1}\\= \frac{(b-a)^n}{(n-1)!}f^{(n)}[a + t(b-a)](1-t)^{n-1}- (b-a)f'[a+t(b-a)]. $$

Integrating over $[0,1]$,

$$-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(b-a)^k}{k!}f^{(k)}(a) \\= \frac{(b-a)^n}{(n-1)!}\int_0^1 f^{(n)}[a + t(b-a)](1-t)^{n-1} \, dt-(b-a)\int_0^1f'[a+t(b-a)] \, dt\\=\frac{(b-a)^n}{(n-1)!}\int_0^1 f^{(n)}[a + t(b-a)](1-t)^{n-1} \, dt-f(b) + f(a).$$

Rearranging,

$$f(b) = f(a) + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(b-a)^k}{k!}f^{(k)}(a) + \frac{(b-a)^n}{(n-1)!}\int_0^1 f^{(n)}[a + t(b-a)](1-t)^{n-1} \, dt.$$

This is the Taylor series with the integral form of the remainder -- derived without invoking the MVT.